# 0x80070057 error after deploying to the hololens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I genuinely don't even know where to start.

This problem started occurring after I installed the mrtk v2.0.
Before that I was able to deploy without any issue.

The error I'm getting is a pop-up with this text:

```
Unable to start debugging.

Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.
```

Like so:

[image: Screenshot Error]

Comment: Can you please provide some additional details?  1. What version of Visual Studio? (Help -> About should show something like "16.2.3").  2. What specific steps are you taking that lead to this error? (e.g., 'open the project, switch to the Release | x86 configuration, set the debug target to Device and press F5')

Comment: Visual studio version - Visual studio community 2017 version 15.9.16. I build the project from unity as an UWP project x86 sdk version 10.0.18362.0 . Then opened the generated solution. Started without debugging on debug mode x86 on device. It compiles and then tries to deploy. That is where is fails.

Comment: @Robin, can you check the minimum sdk version for your project (inside of Visual Studio)? There is an issue in MRTK 2.0.0 where it gets set to the latest SDK version (18362) when it should be between 10240 and 17763.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being re-targeting the solution to sdk version 17763 inside visual studio. Still building with 18362 in unity.

Thank you @davidkline-ms for suggesting trying this.